# Importing a package into all modules in a directory

Tags: python, python-import

What is the most canonical way to import a package into multiple files? Is the best way to import into a common module and then import that, or is there a way to do it somewhere like __init__.py?

This is the repetition I'm trying to avoid:

**file1.py**

```
from typing import NoReturn
...
```

**file2.py**

```
from typing import NoReturn
...
```

**file3.py**

```
from typing import NoReturn
...
```

Comment: I really don't think this is a repetition. You're good.

Comment: This is a design feature of python. Without implicit imports you have to then deal with management of the order things are imported in different files and that can be a mess. For reference, see any large php project and how imports are handled.

Comment: Thanks all for the Python info -- would also appreciate feedback from the downvoter on any issues with the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically no. The `NoReturn` or whatsoever must be imported from somewhere.

You could "inject" an attribute to a module from "outside" like this:

```
# this is __init__py

from typing import NoReturn

from . import file1
from . import file2

file1.NoReturn = file2.NoReturn = NoReturn
```

but:

- it's an ugly hack,
- the attribute is added after the import, so it is of limited use:

i.e.

```
# this is file1.py

def func() -> NoReturn:   # will fail, NoReturn undefined at import time
    raise ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the more explicit import in each file is the way to go.